# Logstash Web UI doesn't start

Tags: logging, redis, elasticsearch, logstash

I'm facing exceptions when I try to start Logstash with web front-end despite I followed all steps at [official tutorial](http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.10/tutorials/getting-started-centralized). First of all I tried `logstash-1.1.10-flatjar.jar`, it even didn't start too. Then I found [this issue](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1015) so I downloaded `logstash-1.1.11.dev-flatjar.jar` as it is advised. Now it doesn't give any errors when I initialize it. But when I locate my browser to `myserver:9292` I see errors on both console and web ui like these:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - file:/home/zimtest/Downloads/logstash-1.1.11.dev-flatjar.jar!/logstash/web/views/search/results.haml
    org/jruby/RubyFile.java:333:in `initialize'
    org/jruby/RubyIO.java:1179:in `open'
    jar:file:/home/zimtest/Downloads/logstash-1.1.11.dev-flatjar.jar!/tilt/template.rb:91:in `read_template_file'
```

[image: Web UI Errors]

I'm using official tutorial's configuration; here's my `indexer.conf` file:

```
input {
  redis {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    type => "redis-input"
    # these settings should match the output of the agent
    data_type => "list"
    key => "logstash"

    # We use json_event here since the sender is a logstash agent
    format => "json_event"
  }
}

output {
  stdout { debug => true debug_format => "json"}

  elasticsearch {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was dealing with the same issue.

I opened up the jar and found the views folder was buried and extra folder deeper than we're expecting. Should work long enough until they fix it in the next version.

Quick solution that worked for me:

```
#extract folder
jar xfv logstash-1.1.11.dev-flatjar.jar logstash/web/views

#move files around
cp -r logstash/web/views/views/ logstash/web/
rm -rf logstash/web/views/views

# push files in jar
jar uvf logstash-1.1.11.dev-flatjar.jar logstash/web/views/
```

Comment: thanks @Nathan for your solution.. worked for me too; but I hope they fix this bug in next versions.

Comment: Looks like they did https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1015?focusedCommentId=17142&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-17142

Comment: Considering using logstash / elastic to process SO's web logs, problem with logstash tutorial, answer on SO :-P

Comment: @talha06 I just downloaded 1.1.12 and had no problems

Comment: Is there a windows version for lumberjack ? or something similar that can send logs created by nlog to logstash ?

Comment: I'm also using 1.1.12 and I encounter this problem. The workaround posted by Nathan works for me perfectly. Thanks.