# Running logstash Web UI

Tags: logstash

I am a newbie in using logstash and I am trying to start off the web ui but can't seem to be able to trigger it. I get an exception everytime I try run the web ui. This is the long exception I get. I am using windows 7. Any kind of advice is highly appreciated. I tried the following on stackoverflow but I had problems with figuring out how to implement Nathan's solution for the 'cp' and 'rm' command work. [Logstash Web UI doesn't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16403031/logstash-web-ui-doesnt-start).

```
C:\MyPrograms\logstash>java -jar logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar agent -f logstash-s
imple.conf -- web --backend elasticsearch://localhost/
{:expand_path=>["jar:file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!/l
ogstash/../../locales/en.yml", "jar:file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13
-flatjar.jar!/locales/en.yml"]}
{:expand_path=>["file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!/META-
INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rake-10.0.3", "file:/C:/MyPrograms/logs
tash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/
rake-10.0.3"]}
{:expand_path=>["file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!/addre
ssable/idna/../../../data/unicode.data", "file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-
1.1.13-flatjar.jar!/data/unicode.data"]}
Exception in thread "LogStash::Runner" org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (Err
no::ENOENT) No such directory: file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flat
jar.jar!C:/backports/1.8.7/stdlib
        at org.jruby.RubyDir.entries(org/jruby/RubyDir.java:366)
        at RUBY.extend_relative(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-fla
tjar.jar!/backports/tools.rb:68)
        at RUBY.(root)(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!
/backports/1.8.7/stdlib.rb:1)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027)
        at Kernel.require(jar:file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatj
ar.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36)
        at Kernel.require(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.j
ar!/logstash/JRUBY-6970.rb:13)
        at Kernel.require_with_backports(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1
.1.13-flatjar.jar!/backports/tools.rb:328)
        at RUBY.(root)(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!
/backports/tools.rb:1)
        at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613)
        at RUBY.require_relative_dir(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.1
3-flatjar.jar!/backports/tools.rb:22)
        at RUBY.require_relative_dir(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.1
3-flatjar.jar!/backports/tools.rb:17)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027)
        at Kernel.require(jar:file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatj
ar.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36)
        at Kernel.require(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.j
ar!/logstash/JRUBY-6970.rb:13)
        at RUBY.(root)(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!
/backports/1.8.7.rb:3)
        at RUBY.(root)(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!
/backports/tools.rb:1)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027)
        at Kernel.require(jar:file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatj
ar.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36)
        at Kernel.require(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.j
ar!/logstash/JRUBY-6970.rb:13)
        at RUBY.require_with_backports(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1
.13-flatjar.jar!/backports/tools.rb:328)
        at RUBY.(root)(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!
/backports/1.8.rb:2)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027)
        at Kernel.require(jar:file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatj
ar.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36)
        at Kernel.require(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.j
ar!/logstash/JRUBY-6970.rb:13)
        at RUBY.(root)(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!
/backports/tools.rb:1)
        at RUBY.require_with_backports(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1
.13-flatjar.jar!/backports/tools.rb:328)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027)
        at Kernel.require(jar:file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatj
ar.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36)
        at Kernel.require(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.j
ar!/logstash/JRUBY-6970.rb:13)
        at RUBY.(root)(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!
/backports/1.9.1.rb:2)
        at RUBY.(root)(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!
/backports/tools.rb:1)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027)
        at Kernel.require(jar:file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatj
ar.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36)
        at Kernel.require(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.j
ar!/logstash/JRUBY-6970.rb:13)
        at RUBY.require_with_backports(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1
.13-flatjar.jar!/backports/tools.rb:328)
        at RUBY.(root)(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!
/backports/1.9.2.rb:2)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027)
        at Kernel.require(jar:file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatj
ar.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36)
        at Kernel.require(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.j
ar!/logstash/JRUBY-6970.rb:13)
        at RUBY.(root)(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!
/backports/tools.rb:1)
        at RUBY.require_with_backports(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1
.13-flatjar.jar!/backports/tools.rb:328)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027)
        at Kernel.require(jar:file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatj
ar.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36)
        at Kernel.require(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.j
ar!/logstash/JRUBY-6970.rb:13)
        at RUBY.(root)(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!
/backports/1.9.3.rb:2)
        at RUBY.(root)(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!
/backports/tools.rb:1)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027)
        at Kernel.require(jar:file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatj
ar.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36)
        at Kernel.require(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.j
ar!/logstash/JRUBY-6970.rb:13)
        at RUBY.require_with_backports(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1
.13-flatjar.jar!/backports/tools.rb:328)
        at RUBY.(root)(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!
/backports/1.9.rb:2)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027)
        at Kernel.require(jar:file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatj
ar.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36)
        at Kernel.require(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.j
ar!/logstash/JRUBY-6970.rb:13)
        at RUBY.(root)(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!
/backports/tools.rb:1)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027)
        at Kernel.require(jar:file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatj
ar.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36)
        at Kernel.require(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.j
ar!/logstash/JRUBY-6970.rb:13)
        at RUBY.require_with_backports(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1
.13-flatjar.jar!/backports/tools.rb:328)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027)
        at Kernel.require(jar:file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatj
ar.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36)
        at Kernel.require(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.j
ar!/logstash/JRUBY-6970.rb:13)
        at RUBY.(root)(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!
/backports/2.0.0.rb:2)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027)
        at Kernel.require(jar:file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatj
ar.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36)
        at Kernel.require(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.j
ar!/logstash/JRUBY-6970.rb:13)
        at RUBY.(root)(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.jar!
/backports/tools.rb:1)
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027)
        at Kernel.require(jar:file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatj
ar.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36)
        at Kernel.require(file:/C:/MyPrograms/logstash/logstash-1.1.13-flatjar.j
ar!/logstash/JRUBY-6970.rb:13)
        at logstash.runner.run(logstash/runner.rb:104)
        at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:249)
        at logstash.runner.run(logstash/runner.rb:199)
        at logstash.runner.main(logstash/runner.rb:74)
        at logstash.runner.(root)(logstash/runner.rb:224)

C:\MyPrograms\logstash>
```

Comment: I also get the same error on Windows 7. Is it true that it works on Ubuntu?

Comment: Hi Mawia, yes in Ubuntu everything seems to be less faulty than in Windows as Logstash was developed mostly looking at Ubuntu since its open source, it has a lot of support in Ubuntu rather in windows, so I ended up switching to Ubuntu so to make things work and all was good.

Comment: I also installed logstash in **CentOS** and everything is fine. Windows 7 is giving problem with Web UI.

Comment: why do they even bother making a win version

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a current bug with logstash which is not yet resolved - https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1066

Comment: Hi Richard thank you for the response, I decided to install VirtualBox and use Ubuntu for logstash and everything is working fine now. Thank you for the info really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, this is currently a bug in logstash for Windows 7 users.

**Helpful tips for  Windows 7 users:**

- You may still run it properly without using the Web UI. The logstash API itself is working fine. Even the embedded ElasticSearch included in the logstash jar is working fine.
- For the Web UI, you may install Kibana separately.
- Kibana needs Ruby.  Install Ruby from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/
- You may need to install Ruby Development Kit as well and run “ruby dk.rb init” and “ruby dk.rb install” to bind it to ruby installations. [(Helpfull link)](https://github.com/rashidkpc/Kibana/wiki/Kibana-ruby-on-Windows-%28from-scratch%29)
- To install Kibana, follow the steps in http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/installation/
- By default, kibana listens to localhost:9200. You may change it in KibanaConfig.rb